# variable increment doesn't work

Tags: php

When I launch my web page, increment doesn't work correctly!

It should go like this: `$i = from 1 to x (0,1,2,3,4,5,6 etc..)`.
But instead it jumps over every step giving result of `(1,3,5,7 etc..)`.

Why is this code doing this?

```
<ul class="about">
        <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = 1");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $bioText = $row['bio'];
            }

            $endBioTxt = explode("\n", $bioText);

            for ($i=0; $i < count($endBioTxt);)
            {
                if (checkNum($i) == true)
                {
                    echo "<li class='left'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";
                    echo $i;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li class='right'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";
                    echo $i;
                }
                $i++;
            }


            // Function to check if number is prime
            function checkNum($num){
              return ($num % 2) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            }

        ?>
    </ul>
```

Output:

> Sometext!(right side)
>   0
>   1
>   Sometext2!(right side)
>   2
>   3
>   ...

Comment: Your output is `0, 1, 2, 3` that's what you want right?

Comment: Also `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $bioText = $row['bio'];
            }` just contains the value of the last row. Don't thinnk that's waht you want???

Comment: Also: do you really need a function just for doing a modulo calculation?

Comment: His output is `1, 3, 4`, he needs `0, 1, 2`

Comment: @Than he should fix the ouput in his answer to represent what it outputs :P

Comment: My output is correct , go check out web www.dacesimane.lv ->bio page.

Variable $i doesn't act like integer but rather like an array of $i and $i++. You can see it skips true test and the goes for else and with echo prints out 0<br />1

Comment: @skmasq: Your website shows nothing, just a black page.

Comment: it owrks now, im testing all the time.

Comment: IS It possible that $endBioTxt[] modifies $i? Because I ran a test and anomaly shows only after it prints out this variable!!!

Comment: Found the problem. It's When I use explode , otherwise everythings works if you manually input variables in array.

Comment: Found the problem. It's When I use explode , otherwise everythings works if you manually input variables in array. EDIT: Strange nature of array only occurs when you explode with \n or <br /> but when you do it with single space it works just fine.

Comment: @skmasq: code or didn't happen

Comment: ANSWER is right here:
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$bioText = $row['bio'];
$endBioTxt = explode("\n\n\n", str_replace("\r","\n",$bioText),-1);
$totalElements = count($endBioTxt);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalElements; $i++)
{if ($i % 2){echo "<li class='right'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";}
else{echo "<li class='left'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";}}
?>
Problem was the \r needed to be replaced , so I replaced them with \n and then used it as third \n in explode first argument ,and it worked! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, please test it in your environment and then uncomment/comment what you need.

```
<?php

// This is how query should look like, not big fan of PHP but as far as I remember...
/*
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$bioText = $row['bio'];
$endBioTxt = explode("\n", $bioText);
*/

$endBioTxt[0] = "one";
$endBioTxt[1] = "two";
$endBioTxt[2] = "three";
$endBioTxt[3] = "four";
$endBioTxt[4] = "five";

$totalElements = count($endBioTxt);

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalElements; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 2)
    {
        echo "<li class='left'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<li class='right'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";
    }

    /*
    // This is how you should test if all your array elements are set
    if (isset($endBioTxt[$i]) == false)
    {
        echo "Array has some values that are not set...";
    }
    */
}
```

**Edit 1**

Try using `$endBioTxt = preg_split('/$\R?^/m', $bioTxt);` instead of `explode`.

Comment: This manually works. But when you but $endBioTxt trough explode with \n or <br /> it has strange nature.

Answer (score 3):

Please DONT do this as other suggested:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($endBioTxt); $i++)
```

do this:

```
$count = count($endBioTxt);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
}
```

No need to calculate the count every iteration.

Nacereddine was correct though about the fact that you don't need to do:

```
$i++;
```

inside your loop since the preferred (correct?) syntax is doing it in your loop call.

**EDIT**

You code just looks 'strange' to me.

Why are you doing:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
     $bioText = $row['bio'];
 }
```

???

That would just set `$bioText` with the last record (bio value) in the recordset.

**EDIT 2**

Also I don't think you really need a function to calculate the modulo of a number.

**EDIT 3**

If I understand your answer correctly you want 0 to be in the `left li` and 1 in the `right li` 2 in the `left` again and so on.

This should do it:

```
        $endBioTxt = explode("\n", $bioText);

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($endBioTxt as $txt)
        {
            $class = 'left';
            if ($i%2 == 1) {
                $class = 'right';
            }

            echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><div>'.$txt.'</div></li>';
            echo $i; // no idea why you want to do this since it would be invalid html

            $i++;
        }
```

Comment: 1) I know I don't to calculate every iteration, but it's not relavent to problem...
2) About $i++ , it's correct syntax, and again not an answer
3) Because it doesn't matter how I get my results as long as I get them.
4) I think I need that function because it's there for a purpose

Comment: The comment says that the function calculates whether a number is prime !!

Comment: @skmasq: 1) It might not be but it is still incorrect. Other users might see it and think it is. StackOverflow is not only for you to see you know. 3) here on SO we are not `we shoudln't do this but it gets the job done`. Again your not the only reader of SO. 4) No you don't need it. I can see the purpose and you don't need it (unless you haven't shared all the relevant code, which would be an error on your side). 5) I don't know whether it is the fact that english isn't your native language, but your comment smell profane while I'm trying to help you.

Comment: @skmasq: because your are new and because I'm don't know whether your comment was meant to be profane I give you the benefit of the doubt adn edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Your for statement should be:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($endBioTxt); $i++)
```

see http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: He/She manually increments `$i` at the end of the for loop. While your form is preferred, his code does increment correctly.

Comment: -1 | It doesn't *have* to be like this. He put his `$i++` in the body of the for, and nothing is executed in expression 3 of the for loop. That is *perfectly* valid.

Comment: It's the same, and problem isn't where $i++ is standing. Problem is it echo's me 2 numbers like an array 01 then 23 etc...

Comment: So then how exactly does this even answer the question? Moving the `$i++` from the body to the expression will make absolutely no difference in this question.

Answer (score 2):

`$i++;` You don't need this line inside a `for` loop, it's withing the `for` loop declaration that you should put it.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($endBioTxt);$i++)
{
    if (checkNum($i) == true)
    {
        echo "<li class='left'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";
        echo $i;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<li class='right'><div>".$endBioTxt[$i]."</div></li>";
        echo $i;
    }
    //$i++; You don't need this line inside a for loop otherwise $i will be incremented twice
}
```

**Edit:**  Unrelated but this isn't how you check whether a number is prime or not

```
// Function to check if number is prime
function checkNum($num){
    return ($num % 2) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where $i++ stands ,doh. Problem is... whenever for ($i=0; $i < count($endBioTxt);$i++) or $i++ is inside , it doesnt increase number by 1 , it increases it by two.

Comment: @skmasq: if it increments by two, how come you have 0, 1, 2 **and** 3 in your sample output?

Comment: Clearly you dont understand me ,ok here it goes again:

when any $n or $i or $whatever variable goes into this loop and is $var++ it increases two times.

If you send in $i=0 then it will be 0,1 then it increases and is 2,3 then it again incrases 2 times.

Comment: i check if its even or odd not prime, my buddy wrote it prime like noob